# Initialization of rxjs observables, switchMap with Angular routing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to build an **angular**-universal/e-commerce app, I've been learning a lot, the last 2 days I hit a brick wall when I started using **RxJS** and Observables more often.

Now I'm developing a category page since `ActivatedRoute` Observable is an exception that I don't need to unsubscribe from I thought if I make my `HttpClient` call inside `switchMap` that is connected to route observable I could somehow **avoid nested subscriptions**, I'm not very experienced with RxJS yet, so I don't know if I missed anything that's crucial and could cause memory leaks if you see anything that can go very wrong please let me know.

The first question is about the initialization of Observable, when I use

```
categoryProducts$: Observable<CategoryProduct[]>;
```

I get an error

```
Property 'categoryProducts$' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

It works when I initialize a new Observable to the property, I'm not sure if that's a good way to do it, why do I need to initialize a new Observable ?, I would love to hear opinions about this and possible different solutions.

```
 categoryProducts$: Observable<CategoryProduct[]> = new Observable<CategoryProduct[]>();
```

category-page.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Category, CategoryProduct } from 'src/app/core/interfaces/category';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/core/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category-page',
  templateUrl: './category-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category-page.component.scss'],
})
export class CategoryPageComponent implements OnInit {
  categoryProducts$: Observable<CategoryProduct[]> = new Observable<
    CategoryProduct[]
  >();
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    let category$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params: Params) =>
        this.dataService.loadCategoryData(params['category-slug'])
      )
    );
    this.categoryProducts$ = category$.pipe(
      map((res: Category) => res.products.nodes)
    );
  }
}
```

category-page.component.html

I'm not really sure how to display data in the **component template** when the **requested data** is ready, how do I know that requested data is ready to display in the component template?

I want to display a message or spinner while waiting for data but the `else` block never gets executed even after I change URLs via routerLink and I don' really understand why, I would guess that `categoryProducts$` always exists because I initialized it with `new` keyword, so even tho is empty it returns true. How do I fix this?, I want to show a message while the user is waiting for a response?, right now in between changing URL and request data being received from the server user is being shown data from the previous request, and when new request data comes in it replaces old data right away without any message.

```
<div *ngIf="categoryProducts$ | async as products; else loading">
  <a
    *ngFor="let product of products"
    routerLink="/produkt/{{ product.desiredSlug }}"
    >{{ product.name }}</a
  >
</div>
<ng-template #loading> Content is loading </ng-template>
```

data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Header, MenuItems } from '../interfaces/header';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Category } from '../interfaces/category';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  devUrl: String = 'http://localhost:4200';

  loadMenu(): Observable<MenuItems[]> {
    return this.http.get<Header>(`${this.devUrl}/api/menu`).pipe(
      map((res: Header) => res.productCategories.nodes),
      shareReplay()
    );
  }
  loadCategoryData(slug: string): Observable<Category> {
    return this.http.get<Category>(`${this.devUrl}/api/category/${slug}`).pipe(
      map((res: Category) => res),
      shareReplay()
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
export interface Category {
  __typename: string;
  products: {
    pageInfo: {
      hasNextPage: boolean;
    };
    nodes: CategoryProduct[];
  };
}
export interface CategoryProduct {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  desiredSlug: string | null;
  description: string | null;
  price: string;
  shortDescription: string;
}
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-asyncpipe-simple-example-ezay2v?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. How to initialize Observable in Angular 12?**

Correct initialization of observable is

```
categoryProducts$: Observable<CategoryWrapper> = new Observable<CategoryWrapper>();
```

Since I'm not planning to share data with other components `Observable` was the best choice for this case, in another case, I would look at `Subject` or `BehaviourSubject`.

**2. How to display loading message while waiting for data from observable with `async` pipe?**

After long hours of research and reading about **RxJS**, I found an [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/angular-show-loading-indicator-when-obs-async-is-not-yet-resolved-9d8e5497dd8) that was very helpful, in my previous code after the first call data was always in the **stream** from previous `HTTP` calls that's why if/else only worked on the first load because nothing was removed nor new data was added.

```
<div *ngIf="categoryProducts$ | async as products; else loading">
</div>
<ng-template #loading> Content is loading </ng-template>
```

In the end, the code I used was the one below, `concat` that merged `of({ loading: true })` and `dataService.loadCategoryData` into single observable with `of` being fired always before `HTTP` request so we could indicate to the template that request will be fired and we are waiting for data, `switchMap` flattened that observable with params observable which I could pass into my template with `$category | async` pipe that automatically subscribes and unsubscribes from the stream.

```
this.category$ = this.route.params.pipe(
      switchMap((params: Params) =>
        concat(
          of({ loading: true }),
          this.dataService
            .loadCategoryData(params['category-slug'])
            .pipe(map((res) => ({ loading: false, res })))
        )
      )
    );
```

The component template looks like this if `category$` exists, and it does, because `of` is being fired first, and it only has `category.loading` property and it is set to `true` so we display a loading message to the user. When the result of `dataService.loadCategoryData` comes in we have `category.res` available so we can display that in the template, `category.loading` is being set to `false` so our loading message doesn't display.

```
<div *ngIf="category$ | async as category">
  <div *ngIf="category.loading">Loading ...</div>
  <div *ngIf="category.res">
    <a
      *ngFor="let product of category.res.products.nodes"
      routerLink="/produkt/{{ product.desiredSlug }}"
      >{{ product.name }}</a
    >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using BehaviorSubject, Change

```
categoryProducts$: Observable<CategoryProduct[]> = new Observable<CategoryProduct[]>();
```

to

```
categoryProducts$: Observable<CategoryProduct[]> = new BehaviorSubject<CategoryProduct[]>([]);
```

Also remove shareReplay:

```
  loadCategoryData(slug: string): Observable<Category> {
    return this.http.get<Category>(`${this.devUrl}/api/category/${slug}`).pipe(
      map((res: Category) => res)
    );
  }
```

Comment: I tried it unfortunately I got an error: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CategoryProduct[]'. 16 >(null); I added interfaces to question in edit –